# Serializing a HttpSession object

Tags: java, jsp, session

I tried to serialize the HttpSession object and got the following exeption

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1081)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:302)
at com.tps.Session.saveSession(Session.java:16)
at org.apache.jsp.setSession_jsp._jspService(setSession_jsp.java:56)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why did you try and do this?  `HttpSession` objects are not serializable, and not supposed to be.

If you need to save the *contents* of the session, then iterate over the session attributes individually, and serialize those.

Comment: how about a WebSocketSession, which you need to send message to client

Answer (score 7):

In addition, remember that objects stored in HttpSession should be Serializable, especially if you're deploying your web application to a cluster, in which case the session may need to move from one JVM to another.
 
This rule is not enforced by the HttpSession.setAttribute method that takes an Object as argument instead of Serializable, so it's up to the developers to follow this good practice.

[For more information.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/508632/Servlets/java/Serialization-HTTPSession-object)

Comment: This is not related to the concrete quesiton/problem at all.

Comment: This is related to the original question/problem. It provides additional insights to the accepted answer. This can help others who struggle to understand what is and is not serializable in a HttpSession.